# Three Questions about a weighted right shift operator.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $T:l^{2}\rightarrow l^{2}$ be a bounded operator defined as follows,

If $x=\left( x_{1},x_{2},...\right) $ and $Tx=\left( y_{1},y_{2},...\right) $
then

$y_{n}=0 \text{ if }n=1 $

$\text{ }=\frac{x_{2^{i}}}{i} \text{ if }3\leq n=2^{i}+1 $

$\text{ }=x_{n-1} \text{ else}$

So we have :

$Tx=\left( 0,x_{1},\frac{x_{2}}{1},x_{3},\frac{x_{4}}{2},x_{5},x_{6},x_{7},%
\frac{x_{8}}{3},...\right) $

My questions are :

1) Is $\mathcal{R}\left( T\right) $ closed ?

2) Is $\mathcal{R}\left( T-\lambda I\right) $ closed for sufficiently
small $\left\vert \lambda \right\vert >0$ ?

3) Do we have for some $x\in l^{2}\setminus \left\{ 0\right\},$ $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{%
\lim }\left\Vert T^{n}x\right\Vert ^{\frac{1}{n}}=0$ ?

Thank you !

Comment: No to 1) If () is closed, then  is continuously invertible on (), but −12+1=2.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: To answer 3) try $x=(0,1,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!